# Replace specific character only when within a boundary in R

Tags: r, regex

How to replace a specific character only when it is accompanied by other characters without eliminating the latter?

for example

```
x <- "Elena has u$s 10,000. She's married.But she's not happy.Her husband's not happy either."

gsub("([a-z])\\.+([A-Z])", ". ", x)

#[1] "Elena has u$s 10,000. She's marrie. ut she's not happ. er husband's not happy either."
```

This way I lose the character before the dot and the character after the dot

I want my result to be as follows:

```
#[1] "Elena has u$s 10,000. She's married. But she's not happy. Her husband's not happy either."
```

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do and what is your expected output ?

Comment: I want to separate the sentences that are stuck together by a dot without space, with a dot with space without losing the characters that delimit the dot

Comment: I want my result to be as follows: #[1] "Elena has u$s 10,000. She's married. But she's not happy. Her husband's not happy either."

Comment: How is it different than what you have in `x` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use positive lookahead regex.

```
gsub("([a-z]\\.)(?=[A-Z])", "\\1 ", x, perl = TRUE)
#[1] "Elena has u$s 10,000. She's married. But she's not happy. Her husband's not happy either."
```

Comment: Is perfect. Thanks Ronak!

Answer (score 0):

We can use two capture groups without using  lookahead

```
gsub("([a-z]\\.)([A-Z])", "\\1 \\2", x, perl = TRUE)
#[1] "Elena has u$s 10,000. She's married. But she's not happy. Her husband's not happy either."
```